# Proving injectivity of a function that modifies binary strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics, bit-strings

"$f : \{ 0, 1 \}^3 \rightarrow \{ 0, 1 \}^4$ is given by adding a copy of the first bit to the end of the binary string."

An example would be $f(abc) = abca$, and I am asked to prove whether or not this function is injective.

I initially considered using an "If $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a = b$" proof but this is a different kind of function so it (probably) warrants a different kind of proof.

Then I went back to the $f(abc) = abca$ example to think about this problem on a more intuitive level; are there any other inputs such that $f$ generates $abca$? How do I even prove that two binary strings are equal other than telling the reader to just look at it?

I've thought a lot about this problem but haven't been able to formulate any of my ideas into a coherent proof thus far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The _rigorous_ proof will hang on how you've defined $\{0,1\}^n$ (for $n=3$ or $n=4$).

Comment: No reason your first attempt wouldn't work. If your mapping is given by $abc \mapsto abca$, and you have two equal binary strings $abca$ and $rstr$, what does this tell you about $abc$ and $rst$?. Also, a disclaimer: i'm assuming you are asking about the string itself, not the integer value it represents